# jdbctemplate and optimistic locking

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate, optimistic-locking

In the project I'm in Hibernate and Spring jdbctemplate are mixed. I added optimistic locking. Hibernate works great with versioning but now I have to tansform all this jdbctemplate code to use versioning too.

Is there something like LockingJdbcTemplate (like SimpleJdbcTemplate)? I was thinking I could  implement a generic update method

```
update(String tableName, String columnsSql, String whereSql, Long version, Object... params)
```

Where I could:

- append version=version+1 to columnSql
- append version=? to whereSql
- add version number to correct place within params (separate param is forcing to pass that value)
- Check that exactly 1 item was updated and throw StaleObjectStateException otherwise

Is there any library that would wrap jdbctemplate and do something similar for me? Don't want to invent something that exists... :)

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you'll have to add the optimistic locking behavior to your update queries manually.